# Trouble Joining 3 Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to writing SQL queries and have been trying to pull information from 3 different tables and link it together.

Data resides in Microsoft SQL Server.

This is my current query (which is not working the way I intend it to):

```
SELECT h.jhhold, h.jhjob, h.jhpart, h.jhrev, h.jhcust, h.jhextd, o.jadesc, h.jhpqty, o.jaoqty, o.jacqty, o.japo, o.javend 
FROM Jhead AS h
LEFT JOIN jjops AS o ON h.jhjob = o.jajob 
LEFT JOIN hpodt AS p ON h.jhjob = p.hdjob 
WHERE h.jhpcmp = 0 AND o.jatype = 2 AND o.jacqty < o.jaoqty AND japcmp = 0 
ORDER BY h.jhjob
```

To explain what I am trying to do.  I have a job header table **Jhead**, a job detail table **jjops** and a purchase order detail table **hpodt**.  I believe the job number is the primary key in the jhead table.

Here is my problem:  As soon as I add the second left join I end up with a lot of extra lines of duplicated information.

I have tried using the GROUP BY jhead.jhjob but get the following error:

“Column ‘jhead.jhhold’ is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.”

So I researched the error with one of the solutions being to make my GROUP BY look like this:
GROUP BY jhead.jhjob, jhead.jhhold, jhead.jhpart, jhead.jhrev, jhead.jhcust, jhead.jhextd

But then as soon as I put in jhead.jhextd I get this error:
“The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.”

And have now hit a brick wall.  I did see that you can change the type to NVARCHAR.  I don’t really want to be sorting by the description field because it is unique and may be very taxing on the server.  Is there a better way to do this?

**Edit With Sample Data:**
I removed extra fields to simplify the query and have filtered the results for 1 job number.

With only 1 left join:
[image: With only 1 Left Join]

With both left joins:
[image: Second]

ERP software as you can see has multiple jobs under 1 PO# and I am only interested in displaying lines with a job number that matches.
[image: Third]

**QUERY UPDATED**

```
SELECT h.jhhold, h.jhjob, h.jhrev, o.jadesc, h.jhpqty, o.jaoqty, o.jacqty, o.japo, o.javend, p.hdprcd, p.hdrecd
FROM Jhead AS h
LEFT JOIN jjops AS o ON h.jhjob = o.jajob 
LEFT JOIN hpodt AS p ON h.jhjob = p.hdjob 
WHERE h.jhpcmp = 0 AND o.jatype = 2 AND o.jacqty < o.jaoqty AND japcmp = 0 AND p.hdjob = h.jhjob AND p.hdpo = o.japo
ORDER BY h.jhjob
```

This is getting close to what I want.  The problem is now that my jadesc field is duplicating the first result when it should actually be different for each line.

[image: 4]

I filtered to just display one job.  Their should only be one column.

**Getting extra lines but have all the data I need**

```
SELECT h.jhhold, h.jhjob, h.jhrev, o.jadesc, h.jhpqty, o.jaoqty, o.jacqty, o.japo, o.javend, p.hdprcd, p.hdrecd, p.hdseq 
FROM Jhead AS h 
LEFT JOIN jjops AS o ON h.jhjob = o.jajob 
LEFT JOIN hpodt AS p ON h.jhjob = p.hdjob 
WHERE (h.jhpcmp = 0 AND o.jatype = 2 AND o.jacqty < o.jaoqty AND japcmp = 0 AND p.hdjob = h.jhjob AND p.hdpo = o.japo AND p.hdseq = o.jaseq AND o.jaopr != 'PT') 
  OR (h.jhpcmp = 0 AND o.jatype = 2 AND o.jacqty < o.jaoqty AND japcmp = 0 AND o.japo = 0 AND o.jaopr != 'PT')
ORDER BY h.jhjob, o.jaseq
```

Comment: can you post some sample data and then the expected result?  If you have multiple records associated with each `jhjob` and you only want one, which one do you want to return?

Comment: Ill do my best to do that right now.

Comment: Please read and follow this article on using aliases: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Noted. I was aware of that but found it easier for myself to work with the actual table names not realizing that it would be harder for someone else to read.

Comment: What kind of data does `hpodt` contain?  You're not even using any fields from that table in your query.  Every join combines every possible combination of records between the left table and right table (logically, it is more sophisticated and efficient than this in practice), and filters them based on the constraint (such as `h.jhjob = o.jajob`).  If you're constraints do not filter down to a single match for each record in each joined table, then you have this problem with multiples of records.

Comment: Yes I shortened my query to post here and for troubleshooting.  I am trying to get a field from 'hpodt' that shows how many of that PO line we have received and whether the line item has been received complete.  Adding a sum to that field gave me the aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause error again.

Answer (score 0):

I *guess* you want to show detailed information about the `jhead` and `jjops` tables, but just want to show some aggregate information found on the `hpodt` table.

If that's the case, you should do something like this:

```
SELECT
    h.jhhold, h.jhjob, h.jhpart, h.jhrev, h.jhcust, h.jhextd,
    o.jadesc, h.jhpqty, o.jaoqty, o.jacqty, o.japo, o.javend,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hpodt p WHERE p.jhjob = h.hdjob) AS po_line_count,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM hpodt p WHERE p.jhjob = h.hdjob)
        THEN 'found it'
        ELSE 'not found'
    END AS info_on_hpodt
FROM
    Jhead AS h
    LEFT JOIN jjops AS o ON h.jhjob = o.jajob 
WHERE
    h.jhpcmp = 0 AND o.jatype = 2 AND o.jacqty < o.jaoqty AND japcmp = 0 
ORDER BY
    h.jhjob
```

It isn't clear to me which specific information you want from the `hpodt` table, but I guess this strategy of using a sub-query will work by just adding other criteria to its `WHERE` clause.

Another option would be using [window functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx), but the sub-query approach is simpler.

Comment: Hmm, that may be what I need.  I just have to figure out what you did and how to apply it.  I actually have data from all three tables now, but in the case where my PO# 'o.japo = 0' I am for some reason getting values showing up in my columns applying to my 'hpodt' table and this is causing duplicate rows.  No data should be showing for the columns applying to 'hpodt' when my 'o.japo = 0'